# module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel

Tags: signature

I am install a Wifi kernel module (compat.ko) on Ubuntu 20.04, kernel 5.19.
But, the Wifi function not be brought up.
The dmesg show below error message.
[53.071748] compat: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel

It seems kernel module need to be signed.
How to solve this problem ?

Rick

Comment: The 5.19 kernel was from Ubuntu 22.10 which is now EOL & unsupported; yet you mention 20.04??  Ubuntu 20.04 LTS using the GA kernel stack uses 5.4, and using the HWE stack uses 5.15, so your details seem incorrect to me. Are you using Ubuntu?  If so can you clarify your details as 5.19 is no longer a *supported* kernel for Ubuntu (*excluding RISCV64 architecture 22.04 but not 20.04*)

Comment: It is not an error, but an informational message. It will not prevent your wireless from working if the driver is correct. Please edit your question to show: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Because of the software update to the kernel version, the version of Ubuntu 20.04 become 5.19. OK, I change to use Ubuntu 22.04 LTS version.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS does **not** use 5.19 as already stated, so your details are very unclear. Your last comment would imply to me you've corrupted your system sources and thus made your system a *frakensystem* (*broken with parts of different releases thus problems are expected unique to your breakage*) OR your question is incorrect/outdated as it says 20.04.  This is a Q&A site (not a forum), so please correct your question if it's incorrect or needs clarification (*comments are from readers about the question; answers will be to the question itself*)